# ROS OpenCV linker error

Tags: ros, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile a program I have that uses opencv, and I get the following error:

--> Making UTIL
-- Linking popup.o to popup (C++)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.3.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [popup] Error 1
make[1]: *** [binaries] Error 255
make: *** [all] Error 2

However, I do seem to have the necessary files:

/usr/lib$ ls -l

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root          24 2011-11-13 09:20 libopencv_contrib.so -> libopencv_contrib.so.2.3

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root          26 2011-11-13 09:20 libopencv_contrib.so.2.3 -> libopencv_contrib.so.2.3.1

-rw-r--r--  1 root    root      372344 2011-11-11 00:12 libopencv_contrib.so.2.3.1

I also have $LD_LIBRARY_PATH set as follows

$echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/usr/lib

The library is being searched for because I am trying to link to opencv2, in which the manifest at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/opencv2/manifest.xml has:

<\export>
<\cpp cflags="`pkg-config opencv-2.3.1 --cflags`" lflags="`pkg-config opencv-2.3.1 --libs`"/>

And this command returns:
$pkg-config opencv-2.3.1 --libs

-l/usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.3.1 -l/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS (Lucid).  I also just switched from diamondback to electric, which was installed using "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full".

Any advice would be appreciated.  If this is not the appropriate place to ask this question, I apologize, and please direct me to the appropriate place.  Also, if I have not provided sufficient information or explained my question in enough detail, please let me know what additional information I can provide.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11919/ros-opencv-linker-error/) by [davheld](https://answers.ros.org/users/1371/davheld/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In electric, opencv has become a third-party dependency. Try using

`<rosdep name="opencv2.3"/>`

in your `manifest.xml`, rather than a `<depend package=...` line.

Then use `rosmake --rosdep-install` to make sure everything's there.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-13**:
It did. Everything turns green, as you may have noticed.

**Comment by [davheld](https://answers.ros.org/users/1371/davheld/) on 2011-11-13**:
OK I tried to accept your answer - did it work? (Thanks again!)

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-13**:
That does seem strange. Go ahead and accept my answer, please. (Karma!)

**Comment by [davheld](https://answers.ros.org/users/1371/davheld/) on 2011-11-13**:
That seems to have fixed it - thanks so much!

I'm still curious though why the linker could not find "/usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.3.1 " when that file clearly exists in that directory. Any idea?